# XML Parsing error

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I trying to parse XML file but getting parsing error.

Code ::

```
$xmlUrl = 'products.xml';
$xmlStr = file_get_contents($xmlUrl); 
$xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($xmlStr);
```

XML file ::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
    <orderlist>
            <order_no>123123</order_no>
            <date></date>
            <client_name>Knapp's Donut Shop</client_name>
            <sector>54</sector>
    </orderlist>
</result>
```

I am getting error because of this tag

```
<client_name>Knapp's Donut Shop</client_name>
```

Comment: What error are you getting exactly?

Comment: have you tried `addslashes` function before parsing?

Comment: yes I tried addslashes finction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion to a SimpleXML Object and the output works, see code example below.
Check your "products.xml" file for the correct UTF-8 encoding type.

```
<?php

$xml = <<< XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
    <orderlist>
            <order_no>123123</order_no>
            <date></date>
            <client_name>Knapp & Donut Shop</client_name>
            <sector>54</sector>
    </orderlist>
</result>
XML;

$xml = str_replace(array("&amp;", "&"), array("&", "&amp;"), $xml);

$xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($xml);

var_dump($xmlObj);

echo PHP_EOL . $xmlObj->orderlist->client_name;

// Result: Knapp & Donut Shop
```

Comment: Its still giving error on this line **$xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($xml);**

Comment: sorry getting error due to **&**<client_name>Knapp & Donut Shop</client_name>

Comment: The XML is invalid. The **&** must be encoded correctly.

Comment: Updated my answer with a conversion line: **$xml = str_replace(array("&amp;", "&"), array("&", "&amp;"), $xml);**